# subtracting from an array in a struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a quick question concerning **func1 and the first paragraph of the main program**.  Essentially, I don't understand a.word-- (in func1) does.

I've commented it out and nothing in the output for a.word changes, but I don't understand why it's irrelevant.

Is it moving all values down 1?  Or does it just cycle from the last letter to the second-to-last letter, and if so why, when a.word is printed, does the entire "myword" print out?

I'm new to pointers and that whole thing.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo{
int num;
char *word;
struct foo *ptr;
};
void func1(struct foo);
void func2(struct foo*);
void func3(struct foo);

int main() {
struct foo a;
a.num = 5;
a.word = "myword";
func1(a);
printf("1 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);

a.num = 100;
a.word = "secondword";
func2(&a);
printf("2 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);

a.ptr = &a;
a.num = 50;
a.word = "mylastword";
func3(a);
printf("4 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);
}

void func1(struct foo a)
{
while(*(a.word) != '\0')
{
    putchar(*(a.word));
    a.word++;
}
putchar('\n');
if(a.num % 10 != 0)
{ a.num *= 2; }
a.word--;
printf("num is %d\n", a.num);
}

void func2(struct foo *a)
{
while(*(a->word) != '\0')
{
    putchar(*(a->word));
    a->word++;
}
putchar('\n');
if(a->num % 10 != 0)
{ a->num *= 2; }
a->word--;
printf("num is %d\n", (*a).num);
}

 void func3(struct foo a)
 {
if(a.num > a.ptr->num)
{ a.num = 500; }
else
{ a.num = a.ptr->num + 1; }

a.word = "myotherword";
a.ptr->word = "yetanotherword";
printf("3  %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);
}
```

Comment: If you are new to pointers,and if this program is not your own,then you could have only presented the relevant section in your question,instead of the whole program.Anyways,look up "pointer arithmetic" online.It's easy,but it will take practice to understand it well.Many people find pointers difficult in C (initially).

Comment: I'm reviewing for an upcoming test and want to get all of the wrinkles ironed out.  As far as not modifying the code, I didn't want to muck up the code and inadvertently change the discussion to irrelevant flaws.  Thank you for the encouragement, though, sincerely. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.word--;
```

Since `aword` is a pointer in your program ,all that the above statement does is make `aword` point to the previous element,instead of the current one it is pointing to. This is basic pointer arithmetic, but since you say you are new to pointers,hence I am "pointing" it out.

It's different from the decrement operator in that,it doesn't just subtact 1 from `aword` but makes it point to the previous element which could be N bytes away from the current element.Had you used

```
a.word++;
```

It would now be the address of/pointer to the next element.In your program, `a.word` is used to store the base address of strings.So `a.word++` will point to the "next character" of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Yes, I am a bit confused by pointers still.  So, since a.word-- simply goes back one value in the array, why does a.word print out "myword" instead of just "d" (since it goes back from the null character)?

Comment: I'll go through your code again if you can't understand what I am about to say in this comment.See, printf() expects the base address of a string for the %s format specifier.A base address is nothing but the address of the first element of the string.If the string is name[10]="John", then the base address is &name[0].In C, this is same as using only `name`,instead of &name[0].So to print "John" in printf(), you pass `name` as argument as printf("%s",name) which is same as printf("%s%,&name[0]).Note that '%s' is for entire string, while '%c' is for a single character

Comment: @user2044189 Now try tweaking the code a bit for better understanding.Use `printf("%c",name)`.It will print "J" as `name` is the address of the first element of the string(which is a character array).But now consider this `printf("%c",name++)`.It will print "o",the second element in the string.Similarly `printf("%c",name+2)` will print "h".That's pointer arithmetic at work at the simplest levels.

Answer (score 2):

The code is show the differences between calling function by-value or by-pointer.

```
void func1(struct foo a)  // call by value
```

In this case every changes on `a` will not apply to caller's input variable.

```
void func2(struct foo *a) // call by pointer
```

It's same as `func1` but in this case every changes on `a` will be affected to the `a` in caller side.

```
struct foo {
int num;
char *word;
struct foo *ptr;
};
```

This structures is an one way linked list, each element points to the next element.

About `a.word--;` which you asked, since this code has many flaws and the logic is unclear. I just can say it will decrease the pointer which is pointing to somewhere is the memory as a `char`.

Comment: Yes, the code is meant to be traced on an exam- this is why it's so convoluted and confusing (the teacher calls it the "nasty trace").
About a.word--;, if you could elaborate on the last sentence of your answer, that would probably unlock my understanding of this.  I'm so close, I can feel it.  

Thank you again.

Comment: @user2044189 Seems like English is not MM's first language.Anyways, what he means is `a.word--` will decrease/decrement the pointer.In pointer arithmetic, this means, if it is currently pointing to an element in an array,then after the decrement it will point to the element before it.Had it been `++` then it would point to the element ahead of it.Suppose a `char*` pointer `ptr` is pointing to 'H' in the string "Him",then after `ptr++` it will point to 'i'.Had it been `ptr+2` or `ptr+=2`,it would point to 'm'.It's that simple.